# Why can't I change the font size of a link tag but can change this on the surrounding text?

Tags: html, css

```css
.full-width-body-no-border-with-padding p, .full-width-body-no-border-with-padding a {
    font-size: 1.2em!important;

}

.full-width-body-no-border-with-padding p, .full-width-body-no-border-with-padding a  {
    color: #898989!important;
 padding-left: 0px!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-width-body-no-border-with-padding xs-hidden">
   <p>Surrounding Text <a class="inline_link" >Wont Change Font Size.</a></p>
   <p>Surrounding Tex <a class="inline_link" >Wont Change Font Siz</a></p>
</div>
```

Right, why can't I change the font size of the `<a>`in keeping with the surrounding text?

I have tried: 
Altering the name attributes in CSS.
I have tried the "parent child" arrangement in the text.
I have tried giving the `<a>` link its own class.
I have checked to see if there was anywhere else in the CSS which gave an `!important` suffix to the class - there isnt.

i'm expecting the link font to change to the same size as the surrounding text. The actual results are that the CSS for the `<a>` tag won't budge.

Comment: Hi! Did you try to do that in isolation in a different HTML to see if it works? If so, in the console you may see what are the styles applied.

Comment: I have just edited the question with inserting the code into the HTML editor on here - same result.

Comment: But it **is** changing the font size...so just remove it...and remove all those `!important` statements too...they care just cluttering up the issue.

Comment: Where are you seeing that it's changing the font size? Why is it working for you and not for me?

Comment: The text of the `a` is slightly bigger than that of the surrounding text of the `p` - because that’s a how the relative font size unit `em` works. The font-size of the `a` is the font size of the parent element, _multiplied_ by the factor 1.2.

Answer (score 3):

just remove those `css` you added. if you need to change font size of all the sentence just add `css` as follows.

```
.full-width-body-no-border-with-padding{
  font-size: 20px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `<p>` and `<a>` to have the same size then just have the CSS rule

```css
.full-width-body-no-border-with-padding {
    font-size: 1.2em;

}

.full-width-body-no-border-with-padding p .full-width-body-no-border-with-padding a  {
    color: #898989!important;
    padding-left: 0px!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-width-body-no-border-with-padding xs-hidden">

            <p>Link Here <a class="inline_link"> Link Not Changing Font Size</a></p>
            <p>Link Here <a class="inline_link"> Link Not Changing Font Size.</a></p>
</div>
```